# Metasploit meterpreter session editing files with Vi editor

Tags: editor, exploit, metasploit

In meterpreter session after exploiting a system, I wanted to edit a .txt file within meterpreter session opened. I used command:

```
meterpreter > edit mypasswords.txt
```

After that, it opened the Vi editor for editing but I really do not like Vi editor at all. I want to know that if there is a way of changing meterpreter' default editor(Vi) to Nano.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it uses your default editor. You can change your default editor to nano by adding or modifying the following lines in your `~/.profile` file:

```
EDITOR=nano
VISUAL=$EDITOR
export EDITOR VISUAL
```